# How to flush the DNS cache in Debian?

Tags: debian, dns, cache

How can I flush the DNS cache in Debian 9.1 with KDE?

Comment: _Which one_?  Debian 9 has ISC's BIND, unbound, Knot Resolver, and PowerDNS Recursor.  And there are even more different softwares (dbndns, djbdns) in Debian "sid". All with caches.

Comment: All cached DNS entries which were fetched from the external DNS servers. I'd be interested in what each of these are about but after all I'm just looking for a simple way to delete all cached entries.

Comment: All of the cached entries _in what software_?  _Which caching software are you running_?

Comment: I'd like to find out. I did not install anything in particular for DNS caching.

Comment: Please show the contents of your `/etc/host.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf` files. Are you sure you have a DNS cache?

Answer (score 19):

If using `systemd-resolved` as your DNS resolver (i.e. the `hosts` line of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file includes the word `resolve` and/or `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the line `nameserver 127.0.0.53`), then this command will flush its cache:

```
$ sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

A newer version of this command seems to be:

```
$ sudo resolvectl flush-caches
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what this command is supposed to do.

Comment: Got this with both command: `Failed to flush caches: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

Comment: Both `sd_bus_open_system: No such file or directory` in debian 11 by WSL2.

Comment: systemd-resolve not found, resolvectl not found

Answer (score 7):

If no DNS name servers (BIND, unbound, Knot Resolver, PowerDNS Recursor, and others) or a DNS resolver (like dnsmasq) or a DNS cache (like nscd) are installed, and they are not installed by default, there is no DNS cache **except** the cache that a web browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc) might keep. Just re-starting the web browser will clear the DNS cache it keeps.

If any DNS server has been installed, probably restarting the service will clear its cache (for example):

```
# sudo systemctl restart bind9
```

The only other local network cache possible is the one that a DNS server running on the network router might keep, just reboot the router.

Answer (score 3):

Also this worked for me: Open the Terminal (either from a menu or an icon or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and type:

```bsh
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

in the terminal.

It cleared my DNS cache, so I could see the WWW page I had been working on with the DNS name I had allocated it. The DNS allocation was done remotely via the Web hosting service. The sudo command via the Terminal asked for the password, and it was my normal user's password since I used `sudo`.

I am using MX Linux 19.1_x64 patito feo and it supports and includes both systemd and init-V functionality and kernels. It is based on Debian GNU/Linux buster 10 stable, and is a desktop distribution called MX Linux 19.1 "patito feo". That is why I can use the command "sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart" without problems in it.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your contribution. Please edit your answer to add some words on which OS flavor/version you are using. The reason is that yours seems to use SysV-Init, whereas in particular in the Linux world, `systemd` is currently the standard, and the service name and syntax to use are different there.

Comment: @AdminBee Nope, this answer works for me, though I have `systemd` as init and `systemctl restart networking` works too.

Comment: It is really weird, `nslookup my.domain.tld` returns the new IP address while `ping my.domain.tld` goes to the old one. Restarting the networking service fixes this.

Comment: @Arnie97 Yes, the answer may work because currently there is limited backwards-compatibility support for the `init.d` mechanism, but it is unlikely to survive long into the future.

Comment: @Arnie97 Some versions of `nslookup` will always bypass any local caches and will instead read `/etc/resolv.conf` and automatically contact the nameserver(s) found in there directly (unless the command line includes a specific nameserver to query). On the other hand, `ping` will always use the currently configured resolver, which may or may not include a caching feature.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to flush the DNS cache in Linux:

- Open your Terminal.
- Restart the name service cache daemon by executing this command:

`sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart`

There are some cases when the nscd daemon might not be installed. In Ubuntu (and other Debian-based distros) you can install it from your Terminal by executing this command:

```
apt-get install nscd
```

Comment: Would it make sense to flush the cache if one needs to first install nscd? Isn't nscd required for DNS caching? Or is it only needed for flushing it?

Comment: Not true at all: you do not need `nscd` to have DNS caching feature. Installing a DNS resolver is enough  to have DNS caching.

Comment: The libc stub resolver does not cache. If _nscd_ **is** installed and configured to cache DNS requests, its DNS cache can be invalidated by `nscd -i hosts`. Installing it definitely won't help with avoiding caching. BTW _nscd_ is rather unstable, I recommend _unscd_ instead of it anyway, which has the same interface.

Comment: The install failed in my Debian 10 VM due to lack of DNS. Rebooting the host (Windows 10) fixed it, but then i didn't need nscd anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

In case you get the following message after running the command:

> Failed to flush caches: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not
> found.

Run the following command in order to enable the service on your Debian:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
```

**Then again run the “systemd-resolve –flush-caches” command.**

You can then check the statistics in order to make sure that your cache size is now zero, thus cleared. Run the following command in order to view the statistics:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --statistics
```