# How to clear DNS cache on Fedora on any other Linux distro

Tags: dns, cache

I've just changed the hosting for my Domain the name got propagated (24 hours passed) I have new page (without SSL because I didn't added it yet on new hosting) on my android phone. But when I open the page in Chromium or Fedora I see old redirect to https.

How can I flush/clear my local DNS so I'll see new page and can do something with new site.

For both my phone and my laptop I use same WiFi so it's not cache in router.

In this question [How to flush the DNS cache in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387292/how-to-flush-the-dns-cache-in-debian) first answer don't work and second is for server that have Bind, I don't have bind, it's not a server.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` look like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 91.239.248.21
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver fe80::1%wlp3s0
```

Comment: Which version? What does `/etc/resolv.conf`contain?

Comment: @muru Fedora 29, also added resolve.conf I've edited the question just afer adding, but forget to save.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be rather the cache of the web browser on Chromium, which contains the old HTTPS page/redirect. Empting the cache of the web browser should help.
More on that topic:
https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-clear-cache